# How to load or show the date only in data gridview without the default time?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

This is my code in Load. Since I can already load the data from database, I wish I could Load it from the date table without the default time or any time with it.

```
string query = @"select InvoiceID,cName,datecreated,addedby,Status
                        from CreateTransmital
                        where Status = 'PENDING'
                        GROUP BY InvoiceID,cName,datecreated,addedby,Status";
        using (SqlConnection xcon = new SqlConnection(@"Server=LAPTOP-JH54BE77\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Transmital;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand xcom = new SqlCommand(query, xcon))
            {
                //xcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", tbsearch.Text);
                SqlDataAdapter xdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(xcom);
                try
                {
                    xcon.Open();
                    DataSet1 xlist = new DataSet1();
                    xdapter.Fill(xlist, "CreateTransmital");
                    
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = xlist.Tables[1];
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    xcon.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: There's no date table - is that a typo ? Could you clarify, do you want to change the values in datecreated ?

Comment: That's the datagridview1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a field to the object that is loading the values on the DataTable.

In that field you will get the Date without the Time, and that's all you will have to do. For example:

```
public class Example {

   public DateTime BirthdayDate { get; set;} // 2021/05/17 14:55:23

   public string BirthdayDateString { get { BirthDayDate.Value.ToShortDateString() }  } // 2021/05/17

}
```